# Count min max occurrences in array of elements from JSON to POJO

Tags: java, jackson, mapping, pojo

I'm having a JSON-structure that looks like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "word": "china",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "word": "kids",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "word": "music",
      "count": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "word": "china",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "kids",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "word": "music",
      "count": 2
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "word": "china",
      "count": 10
    },
    {
      "word": "kids",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "word": "music",
      "count": 2
    }
  ]
]
```

I would like to convert this JSON to a plain old Java object which looks like this:

```
public class Word {
    private String text;
    private Integer min;
    private Integer max;
}
```

I would like the "**min**" and "**max**" properties to represent the minimum and maximum occurrences of that specific word in all elements of the array.

For example, the maximum counts for the word "china" is 10 and the minimum is 0.

I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
        word.text = "china"
        word.min = 0;
        word.max = 10;
```

I'm quite new at Java and this is my first attempt to deserialize something a bit more complex. I've been trying out different options using Jackson ObjectMapper, is this the way to go and how would I accomplish this?

Comment: It would be good to explain in detail what you are trying to achieve this. Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a job for Jackson's data-binding annotations.

It seems like you rather need to introduce [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/news/2017/08/07/bean-validation-2-0-is-a-spec/) into your project, which provides various annotations validating values of your POJOs like [`@Min`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html), [`@Max`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html), etc.

Usage example:

```
public class Word {
    private String text;

    @Min(3)
    private int min;

    @Max(10)
    private int max;
}
```

If you're using Spring Boot, then yyou can add the following Maven starter-dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Alternativelly you can go to [Spring Initialer](https://start.spring.io/) and generate dependencies for your build-tool (Maven or Gradle), peak the `Validation` dependency.

Otherwise (if you're not using Spring), see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) how to Hibernate Validator (which is the reference implementation of the Bean Validation specification) to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use library *Josson* to transform the JSON first.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
public class Word {
    private String text;
    private Integer min;
    private Integer max;

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setMin(Integer min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public void setMax(Integer max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("text=%s min=%d max=%d", text, min, max);
    }
}
```

**Deserialize & Transform**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "  [" +
    "    {\"word\": \"china\", \"count\": 0}," +
    "    {\"word\": \"kids\", \"count\": 1}," +
    "    {\"word\": \"music\", \"count\": 0}" +
    "  ]," +
    "  [" +
    "    {\"word\": \"china\", \"count\": 3}," +
    "    {\"word\": \"kids\", \"count\": 0}," +
    "    {\"word\": \"music\", \"count\": 2}" +
    "  ]," +
    "  [" +
    "    {\"word\": \"china\", \"count\": 10}," +
    "    {\"word\": \"kids\", \"count\": 3}," +
    "    {\"word\": \"music\", \"count\": 2}" +
    "  ]" +
    "]");

JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "flatten()" +
    ".group(word)" +
    ".map(text:word, min:elements.min(count), max:elements.max(count))");

List<Word> words = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(node, new TypeReference<List<Word>>() {});
words.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
text=china min=0 max=10
text=kids min=0 max=3
text=music min=0 max=2
```